# Build to Build upgrade in WIX 3.6

Tags: wix, wix3.6

We have a wix installer with version 1.0.0.1, in the next build the version number will be revised to 1.0.0.2 and so on, How does upgrades work in WIX, so that the product upgrades from 1.0.0.1 to 1.0.0.2.

Comment: Are you trying to do Minor Upgrades or Major Upgrades?

Comment: One thing to keep in mind. When Windows Installer compares versions of .msis, it only compares the first three digits. However if you are using WiX to also create bootstrappers to launch your installer and manage your installation, then the WiX bootstrapper engine will use all four digits. So if you only use .msis, then you may want to think about using the third digit for your build number.